# 404 not found when trying to access index.php

Tags: nginx, php-fpm, http-status-code-404

Recently I have reinstalled a server with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, nginx/1.6.1 and php5-fpm.
When I try to access index.html it's working when I try to access index.php i get "404 Not Found". I double checked the .conf files and I can't find what is the problem.

```
server {
    listen  m.y.i.p:80;
    server_name  www.example.com;
    rewrite ^(.*) http:// example.com$1 permanent;
}

server {
    listen  m.y.i.p:80;
    server_name example.com;

    root /var/www;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    access_log off;
    error_log /var/www/error.log;
    rewrite_log on;
    error_page 403 404 /404.html;

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /404.html;
    location = /404.html {
        root /var/www;
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        # With php5-fpm:
        #fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
    location ~*  \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js)$ {
        expires 365d;
    }
}
```

Please help.
Thank you!

Comment: *Is* there an index.php? What do the logs say?

Comment: there is a an index.php and btw every .php file that i`m trying to access i get 404. the error log is empty.

Comment: Try commenting out the line `error_page 500 502 503 504 /404.html;`. This is probably masking a 500 error and is the reason you are only seeing a 404.

Comment: ty @dartonw. now i get 502 Bad Gateway and still don`t know why?

Comment: There's a problem passing the traffic through to the FastCGI server. Is it actually running?

Comment: it`s running fine

Comment: And is your log still empty? How aobut the log from the fastcgi server?

Comment: nginx log empty and no fastcgi log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turned out to be "502 Bad Gateway" and not "404 Not Found", I`ve found the answer to my problem here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/16497957/1845728.